# Rake Task to populate views with information fetched from an API call

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake-task

I am currently working on a project where I am fetching the upcoming webinars via GoToWebinar API. Everything is working great in the console. Below is the code which is doing just fine from console:

```
1.9.3p125 :003 > require 'gotowebinar'
 => true 
1.9.3p125 :004 > g = GoToWebinar::API.new()
# intializes the webinar with API key and access token

1.9.3p125 :005 > g.get_upcoming_webinars
# Fetches the Upcoming webinars from GoTowebinar
```

Now I need to populate the information fetched from the g.get_upcoming_webinars in the respective views as well. My plan was to put the above code in an action in controller and than populate the respective view with the information. However the application is going to be hosted on Heroku and the client does not want me to put this code in controller to make API calls with every single load. In fact the client wants me to create a rake task which he can run once a day and it populates the view with the information.

I have no idea how do I go about doing this. I have been searching for some resources and also played around with stuff but in vain.

Any help to resolve this matter would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the rake task update your database using the API. Then display the data in your views using the ORM as you would normally in a rails app.

Comment: This was also one of my plans but the client wants a rake task which he can runs daily. So saving the information in the database is not what he wants. Thanks for the suggestion though !

Comment: Running a rake task daily doesn't rule out saving info to the database. Is there another requirement that I am missing here?

Comment: The application is static. It is not utilizing database for anything other than just saving information of the users that sign's up for the specific webinar.Also the client does not want me to populate the database with webinars information.

Comment: Okay. You could generate a partial view in the rake task. Then display the partial in the view as you would normally in rails.

Comment: Ok but the question is how do I go about doing that ??

Comment: You can use `File.open('_some_partial.html.erb', 'w') do |handle|...` in the rake task and write to it with `handle.puts("stuff from the api call")`. Here is an example doing a read: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346108/how-to-write-rake-task-to-import-data-to-rails-app)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10930/discussion-between-seph-and-user814446)