# Creating a data visualization site with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a very large excel spreadsheet that consists of a user name, a location, a date, and some fields of numbers, for example.

```
User,location,date,value1,value2,value3

Steve,NYC,2012,9,1,3
Steve,NYC,2011,3,3,2
Steve,CA,2011,1,2,0
Michael,CA,2012,10,3,2
Michael,CA,2011,10,2,0
```

How would I go about organizing a rails site such that one can view all the values for a certain user?

For example,

```
/users/steve/all
```

would display all the values in descending order of date where user=steve.

```
/users/steve/nyc
```

would display all the values in descending order of date where user=steve and location=nyc.

I think I would need to create a users model and import all the data from the excel into the database, but I'm lost about how to do that.

The application, in essence, would be a simple data visualizer. Maybe I have to separate the database and create a user has_many :locations and locations :belongs_to user, I'm not sure. I want the data to be viewed in all sorts of ways—maybe I want to display all the users from a certain location, or view all the locations of a certain user, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest setting up your model within your rails application first. Then, you can just write a rake task probably similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346108/how-to-write-rake-task-to-import-data-to-rails-app) or you can build it from [scratch](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial). There's also a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to directly import from Excel (e.g. the excel sheets are uploade by a user). You can use one of the following gems to importing data from an Excel Sheet

- [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) Reads new and old excel format (+others)
- [spreadsheet](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/) Reads and writes old exel format

If you only have this one excel sheet it will be far easier to simply export the data to csv and follow the answers given in the stackoverflow question mentioned above.

As for the second part of your question on how to model your database you already had the right idea.

Easiest is to fully model what your domain looks like and transform the data accordingly.