# Import CSV to existing sqlite database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, csv, import, sqlite, rake-task

I've searched all over this forum for solution to the above problem, but everything I tried didn't work. Basically, i have a model Library, with corresponding libraries table in my sqlite3 database. I have a csv file named libraries.csv which contains all the data I want to import into the database.

I tried the method on the second answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461260/how-can-i-import-a-csv-file-via-a-rake-task) but it's still not working. I made sure to create my rake file 'import_libraries.rake in the lib/tasks folder and I also saved the libraries.csv file in that folder but i keep getting this error message:

> rake aborted!
>   Don't know how to build task 'import_libraries' (See
>   full trace by running task with --trace)

This is the current code I'm using:

```
require 'csv'
desc "Imports a CSV file into an ActiveRecord table"
task :import, [:filename] => :environment do    
    CSV.foreach('libraries.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
      Library.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
end
```

But when I run bundle exec rake import_libraries, I get the error message above.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? i would appreciate your help guys. Thanks

*EDIT*

I renamed the rake file from import_libraries.rake to just import.rake On running bundle exec rake import, the error message i now get is:

> rake aborted! invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
>   C:/Users/username/rails_app_name/lib/tasks/import.rake:4:in `block in
>   ' Tasks: TOP => import (See full trace by running task
>   with --trace)

Comment: Could you post the current code you're trying?

Comment: I'm sorry. I just edited my question to include the code now

Comment: Could you post a few lines of the `.csv` file?

Comment: Try adding this line at the beginning of the `import.rake` file: # encoding=utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by using this code:

```
namespace :csv do

  desc "Import CSV Data"
  task :import => :environment do

    require 'csv'

    csv_file_path = 'lib/tasks/libraries.csv'

    CSV.foreach(csv_file_path, headers: true) do |row|
      row = Library.create!({
        :column_name1 => row[0],
        :column_name2 => row[1],
        :column_name3 => row[2],
        .
        . 
        :last_column => row[6]
      })
      puts "Success!"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error you're getting and the task you have defined, you should be calling:

```
bundle exec rake import  #=> you're currently calling import_libraries which indeed doesn't exist
```

With `rake` you call a `task` based on the name you give to the tasks, not on the name of the file (remember you can have many task inside each of those rake files).

Comment: Hi fmendez. Should I in that case rename my rake file to import instead?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can name that file any name you want (it should be in the lib/task). You should, for the sake of clarity, give it a descriptive name. When it comes to executing a rake task what matters is that you use the name you assign to it in `task :name_you_assign_to_the_task` inside the .rake file.

Comment: Hi. Please check out the new error message I now receive. Thanks