# creating rake task for importing data from csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I am creating a rake task to import csv file data to my database (MySQL). Here is what I did but It is not working

```
require 'csv'
namespace :tech do                                                                                                                                          

desc "Import tech from csv file"

task temp: :environment do

file = "tech.csv"

CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
  Temp.create ({
                         :current => row[1],
                         :today => row[2],
                         :week=> row[3],
                         :month => row[4]
                       })
end
```

end
end

but when I run `rake tech:temp` it throws this error

```
Don't know how to build task 'tech:temp'
y/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in    top_level'
 /lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'

 /lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'

 /lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'

  /lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
  lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
  /lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in ` standard_exception_handling'
  lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
  /ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rake:23:in `load'
  /bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I already have Temp model existing and respective table in database after migration

Comment: try removing the `:environment` symbol and run the same `rake tech:temp`

Comment: nope still the same...

Comment: where did you saved the tasks file ? (lib/tasks/import.rake ?)

Comment: I saved in /lib/tasks

Comment: This looks like same problem.. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461260/how-can-i-import-a-csv-file-via-a-rake-task] . Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it looks fine but I already tried but did not work

Comment: Try running `rake -T | grep temp` to see if you already have your task. I guess its not finding ur task which is why it says that

Comment: Yes, it is not finding the task and giving this error
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass

Comment: but it should find it as I have put it in lib/tasks and my other rake takes are working as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue while writing rake task to populate data in database. 
In my case the error was same and it was nothing just running the rake task in wrong manner.

I guess you are doing the same, as per the error I can guess

You are running `rake tech:temp` in which task is temp and namespace is tech, which is wrong you should pass it other was as first you need to give task name then namespace.

so the right command is

```
rake temp:tech
```

It hope this will work. It is silly I know